# how to disable navigation keys in j2me?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui, java-wireless-toolkit

We are using Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 and lcdui package for our j2me application. We want to disable the navigation keys (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT) programmatically. How can I do it?

Comment: are you using Form or Canvas ?

Comment: @Lucifer: we are using Canvas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void keyPressed(int keyCode) {
        int action = getGameAction(keyCode);
        if (action == UP || action == DOWN || action == LEFT || action == RIGHT)
        {}
        else
            super.keyPressed(keyCode);
}
```